# Values after validation for dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list (dynamic) in PHP which pulls data from database and displays accordingly. For the same form I have a validation. Problem what I am facing is the am unable to save the value of the previous selected and it resets to 0 value, incase the validation fails

Further able to change the colour of the drop down box to red incase of validation failure that means it is getting the value but not able to print in the drop down.

Can anyone please help me on this.

See code below:

```
<select name=ddcity value="<?php if(isset($selectedcity)){echo $selectedcity;}?>" 
<?php if(isset($code3) && $code3 == 3){echo "class=error";} ?>>
```

---

Basically What i wanted to know: Is this the way to print in the dropdown

Comment: please post your corresponding code to get help

Comment: <select name=ddcity  value="<?php if(isset($selectedcity)){echo $selectedcity;}?>"<?php if(isset($code3) && $code3 == 3){echo "class=error";} ?>>

Comment: please edit your question and add this code in your question with validation code

Comment: not able to add code in question, i had tried it earlier also but not happening.. sorry

Comment: @Siddesh You should have tried with login and click on "edit" link just below tags, anyway I have edited on your behalf.

Comment: @minesh, thanks for editing for me!! :) actualy am new to stackoverflow

Comment: guys please help me on this question, now code has been uploaded in question :)

Answer (score 0):

Put space between two PHP tags  so that value="XX"class=error is separated by space like value="XX" class=error

If this does not solve your problem, post code where $selectedcity is set, you need to check out whether this variable is having proper value or not.

---

Sorry I did not notice earlier, but it should be something like below:

```
<select name=ddcity <?php if(isset($code3) && $code3 == 3){echo "class='error'";} ?>>
<option value="<?php if(isset($selectedcity) && $selectedcity == "XX"){echo " selected=selected "}?>" value ="XX">XYZ city</option>
</select>
```

You need to compare value inside `option` tags not in `select` tag.

Comment: Hi minesh, yes variables getting proper values!! but i doubt whether in dropdown list this is the proper way to print o not. this is am saying as in even if i give some other calue value in echo such as "HI" its not getting printed

Comment: Hi Minesh, Thanx, but not getting wt exactly u r doing after if(isset($selectedcity).. :(

Comment: $query = "SELECT city FROM vendor GROUP BY city"; $result = mysql_query($query);?><p>CITY:</b></p><p1><label for="city" >Preferred City:</label>
     <select name=ddcity <?php if(isset($code3) && $code3 == 3){echo "class=error";} ?>>
     <option value =0>--Select City--</OPTION></p1>
   <?phpwhile ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {$city = $row['city'];
   echo  "<option value='$city'>$city</option>"; 
   $options ="<option value='$city'>$city</option>"; 
   }

Comment: For above code I have not added your suggested statement <option value="<?php if(isset($selectedcity) && $selectedcity == "XX"){echo " selected=selected "}?>" value ="XX">XYZ city</option>
</select>

Comment: @mitesh.did u happnn to get anything on this? :)